# createjs navigate url link not working for flash movieclip

Tags: createjs

i also tried document.location , windows.location and window.open . but nothing worked out . i am trying this from last frame . 
note : i need to apply this in flash cc movieclip createjs export .

```
/* js 
this.stop();

createjs.Touch.enable(stage);


var poem = new lib.mypoem();
stage.addChild(poem);
poem.x=600;
poem.y=400;
poem.mouseEnabled = true;

poem.addEventListener('click', fl_MouseOverHandler);

function fl_MouseOverHandler(event)
{
       window.open("http://graphicscoder.org/", "_self");
}


*/
```

Comment: What version of CreateJS / Flash are you using? The /*js */ comment-based code is fairly old. Are you sure this code block is running? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: i am using flash cs6  /*js */ is mandatory for createjs . what is the recent toolkitforcreatejs . will my flash cc run correctly if i do not use  /*js */

Comment: Toolkit_for_CreateJS_v1_2.zxp

Comment: Ah. Flash CC and Animate both have JavaScript capabilities now, and CreateJS export is built-in instead of being a panel. The JavaScript comment approach is correct when using the panel.

Answer (score 0):

there is no error in your code but its not working .

there are lots of cause it may not work :

so i have found out some technic to make it working

do not convert your  jpg movieclip directly  rather create a rectangle of  0 opacity in flash stage  and use that as a button
to avoid pixel data security issue . run this from xmapp or any local or remote webserver
always use latest  easeljs link .    https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js”>

if you still do not understand download source : http://graphicscoder.org/my-createjs/createjs-navigate-url-link-not-working-for-flash-movieclip/